# C# - WPF - ColumnGroups Footer? (telerik)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik, radgridview

Can anyone tell me whether it's possible to set a footer for each **ColumnGroups** of a **RadGridView** in WPF using *code behind*?

I am able to do it on normal **GridViewDataColumn** by setting the **Footer** attribute to true but how about the ColumnGroups? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think that this is possible. The telerik documentation has no such feature.

You can set the XAML code behind for normal columns, but not for column groups...

By default though column footers are hidden, so in order to make them visible you have to set the ShowColumnFooters property to True, as per the example:

```
<telerikGrid:RadGridView x:Name="radGridView"
                         ShowColumnFooters="True">
    ...
</telerik:Grid:RadGridView>
```